# email activation failing in django

Tags: django, email, django-views, activation

how im sending the activation email

```
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        email_subject = 'confirm your email !'

        message2= render_to_string('authentication/emailConfirmation.html',{     
            'name':user.first_name + user.last_name,
            'domain':current_site.domain,
            'uid':urlsafe_b64encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token':generate_token.make_token(user)})
        
        email= EmailMessage(
          email_subject,
          message2,
          settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
          [user.email],

        )
        email.send()
```

the activate view

````
from django.core.mail import send_mail ,EmailMessage
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes , force_str
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode
from . tokens import generate_token

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        raise Http404("Invalid activation link")

    if generate_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "Your account has been activated!")
        return redirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        raise ValidationError("Invalid activation link")```

the token.py file
````

from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from six import text_type

class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
return (text_type(user.pk) + text_type(timestamp))

generate_token = TokenGenerator()```

the confirmation email template

```
{% autoescape off %}


Confirmation Link: http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

whenever i click on the confirmation link it automatically fails
[image]

Comment: Please check the `uidb64` and `token` values from the activate view.
Because it is not matched from the saved data which might be from the database, it shows 404 response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might get the uidb64 value from the URL like `"b'MzI='"` so it would be decoded like this:

```py
uidb64 = "b'MzI='"
base64.b64decode(val[2:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem lay in the encoding process. Instead of using `urlsafe_b64encode` from the `base64` module, which is related to Python, the appropriate function to use in the context of Django is `urlsafe_base64_encode` from `django.utils.http`. Since `urlsafe_b64encode` is a Python function, while `urlsafe_base64_encode` is specifically tailored for Django.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).